# Getting error "variables in the training data missing in newdata" in R

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data

When I am performing the prediction for a dataset in R, I am getting the following error:

```
Mode.rf <- randomForest(trX,trYc,ntree=1000,proximity=TRUE)
trts = rbind(trX,ts)
Plu.pred <- predict(Mode.rf,trts,proximity=TRUE)
```

> Error in predict.randomForest(Mode.rf, trts, proximity = TRUE) : 
>         variables in the training data missing in newdata

The below details depict the data of first few samples.

```
trts #In total, 1376 observations out of 95 variables

     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
1     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
2     0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0 

Mode.rf

# Call:
#  randomForest(x = trX, y = trYc, ntree = 1000, proximity = TRUE) 
#                Type of random forest: classification
#                      Number of trees: 1000
# No. of variables tried at each split: 9

#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 80.29%
# Confusion matrix:
#     1  2   3  4 class.error
# 1  74 85 129 99   0.8087855
# 2 106 84 105 58   0.7620397
# 3 125 90  51 76   0.8508772
# 4 114 45  72 62   0.7883959
```

Could someone please help me out in fixing this issue?

Comment: You probably have classes in your `ts` data that are not in `trX`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shared it seems like you are:

1: building a model supplying independent variables (trX) and 1 dependent variable (trYc)

This seems fine to me

2: rowbinding the independent variables from your trainingset to something else

If ts is a set of independent variables  it doesn't make sense for me to bind them to the old data. It would be better to test the new dataset on it's own.
If ts is a new dependent variable you would probably be using cbind instead of rbind (and wrongfully predicting new outcomes on non-matching old data).

If the goal is to use your model in a new dataset be sure to give the new dataset exactly the same columnnames as the first.

you can also keep you dependent and independent variables together in 1 dataframe and use the formula option in randomForst instead ( Y ~ ., data=dataname, etc.)

"." means every other variable in the dataframe.